# Moment.js parsing text as date doesn't seem to match locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

String `12.01.2015` e.g. in Germany stands for Jan 12 2015. But the following code doesn't work as expected:

```
moment.locale('de');
moment('12.01.2015').toString(); // "Tue Dec 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100"
moment('12.01.2015').fromNow(); // "in einem Jahr" (==> locale setting is OK)
```

In locale/de.js there's the following:

```
longDateFormat : {
    ...
    L : 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    ...
}
```

Why isn't the string parsed as I think it should?

Comment: Thanks to other answers, I've solved my problem. Anyway, I've discovered that if you really need to parse a date according to the current locale (not my case), you can do e.g. `moment('12.01.2015', 'L')`. This would be parsed as Dec 1 if locale is `en`, or as Jan 12 if locale is `de`.

Comment: Hopefully you mean *en-us*, as in the great majority of English speaking countries, 12.01.2015 date would be 12 January, 2015.

Comment: By `en` I don't mean the English language, I mean the Moment.js locale identifier, the default locale setting. It's an abbreviation of `en-us`, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Momen't locale sets the desired **output** of moment. Not the input. You will need to supply the input format like this:

```
moment('12.01.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

See [this](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407) github page for more explanation specifically on how this behaviour will change in the future.

You can wrap this in a function so that you do not have to carry the format with you:

```
function germanMoment(date){
    return moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
}
```

And then you can simply use `germanMoment('12.01.2015').fromNow()`which will work as desired.

Comment: If you want to automatically use the current locale:

`moment(date, moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'))`

Answer (score 2):

Moments [parse method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) excpects an ISO 8601 string. You have to specify the date format.

```
moment("12.01.2015", "DD.MM.YYYY")
```